# Windows 10 - Thumbnail of animated webp + ability to view in windows photo viewer?

Tags: windows-10, thumbnails, windows-photo-viewer, webp

I did many things to be able to see the thumbnails of webp files in windows explorer and that I could see them in windows photo viewer.

E.g. WebpCodecSetup installed, K-Lite codec pack full installed, Icaros installed

And it worked. But there are webp images and animated webp files, kinda like gif.

And these animated ones I can't make to work. I can open them in chrome browser.

By that I mean they don't really show up even as static image or single frame. Either chrome icon or default thumbnail - here you can see.

[image]

I would like at least see the thumbnail of them. At best - thumbnail + able to open them in windows photo viewer (at least as single frame).

But I would like to see the thumbnails of these animated webp files and have the ability to open them in windows photo viewer.

Is this possible? How can I achieve that?

Comment: "And these animated ones I can't make to work" does that mean the thumbnail is not displayed for animated webp files or is just the animation not working (thumbnails are to my knowledge never animated soo also thumbnails of videos).

Comment: @Robert I have updated my question :)

Comment: I don't have installed anything webp related and both static and animated webp images have e preview on my Windows 10 system. Are you sure the animated webp files is really a webp file and not something else (GIT, mini video, ..)? Use an hex editor to check (should start with `RIFF` and later may be `WEBPVP8X`).

Comment: @Robert I would like to have that too. It looks like it, the extension is webp + by opening in notepad++ I can see the begginning of the file like `RIFF:3 WEBPVP8X
      ó  ANIM   jhS˙  ANMF`l        ó  (  VP8 Hl  ĐŔ ť*ô>a0•GŁ"ˇ‘»l¤0±5O<ćy§ĽYţÇü˙ůů˙ç?˙˙˙÷Řđ'ČÉw˙=ţ·űż˙˙ţ˝ô˙Î˙ţźýOů˙˙˙ű_öŹńđĆ˙§˙-ű˙˙ßěwô/éäĽţŢz˙˙˙Ăëgçä˙-ýŻ´˙r˙•˙SýŹ¸ŻçŮ?Ň˙‡˙C˙[÷˙˙ÇĘ˙Ú˙Â˙!ţ‹ţ˙·ĎÜ˙Ňµţ˙ý÷ö7ěů§öoö_ÜÓţŃý˙gţWěł»ŃýÁ÷'üÓűýođźż~îżń˙Ş˙u˙çÚ×ëżëżď˙Ł˙[˙óäŻóżí?ň˙Ăš˙ýţÓçź˙˙Ľ` ;

Comment: @Robert maybe it is something related to this `RIFF:3 WEBPVP8X` especially `vp8x` hmmmm

Comment: May be one of the codec packs you have installed has destroyed webp support?

Comment: @Robert I doubt that but I dont really know. What can I do?

Comment: I agree with Robert, as strange as it might sound, you actually don't need nothing to view the thumbnails of webp in File Explorer being them still or animated. All that codecs you installed must have messed up something.